# Is there a way to remove svn working copy? svn autoremove?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to revert checkout of svn repo?

I accidentally checked out huge codebase in my user folder, and it will be really pain to delete everything out manually, is there a way to remove the working copy?

Is there something like `svn autoclean`?

Comment: Your WC must be in <somedir>, can you find this folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVN was not meant to do this, ideally you should checkout into a blank directory. Hindsight is 20/20, so now what you need is a hack.

Create an empty branch in your repo, `svn switch` to that branch. This will update your working copy to that branch, which has nothing in it, so any files under version control should be removed from your working copy. This will leave behind the `.svn` meta info files and folders, which you can deal with individually, which will be much easier than individually figuring out which files are under version control and which aren't

Also if your SVN history has revision 1 as a new, empty repo you can `SVN Update` to that revision, which will do the same as the switch maneuver above, but most repo's I've dealt with  already have a lot of files in revision 1.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of came up with it on the fly. Hope it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks, it could be done by switch to revision 0 of root (the path what you checked out may not have smaller revision), see scripts in http://stackoverflow.com/a/41476171/2465785

Answer (score 0):

`deltree` (on Windows) or `rm -rf` (everywhere else)

Comment: That would also delete my files and folders which I want to keep. I checked out in user/ folder which contains documents etc.

Comment: Yes, I did svn co svpath .

Comment: Did you include the `.` or did you not?

Comment: Then you'll have to somehow determine what paths are under SVNROOT and remove only those.

Comment: Look in .svn/entries and the lines above `file` and `dir` seem to be the ones you need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

From @invertedspear's good idea we can have a simple solution

```
# find your repo root first
root_url=$(svn info --show-item repos-root-url)

# switch to version 0 (must be empty)
svn sw --ignore-ancestry "$root_url"@0

rm -rf .svn
```